# What is an easy way to peel the bark off of a stick?

Tags: traditional-techniques

I am making Escrima Sticks out of wood in my backyard, and I want to peel the bark off of the sticks quickly.

Comment: They're usually made of rattan for durability. Are you sure you want to make them out whatever wood you are making them out of? In any case since you're probably going to want to smooth/round them anyways I'd just use a sharp knife or a spokeshave.

Comment: Do a web search for "stripping wood"

Comment: (@AST "stripping bark from wood", it's all paint stripper otherwise)

Comment: @Jason my mistake - it was "stripping bark" which as the first hit gave the ever favorite boatload of "Images for stripping bark".

Comment: Related: http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2159/how-can-i-debark-wood?rq=1. It's almost a dupe IMO but you are asking about sticks.... Although I don't think I would use actually sticks for this.

Comment: Hire a monkey and tell him its a banana.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a knife blade and make a slit lengthwise. Pour hot water from a kettle along entire slit repeat as needed. Like cornhusking without a microwave.